# R: finding common names in two character lists

Tags: r, list, merge

I'm very new to R and have searched all over but can't find an answer to my specific problem.

I have a program that spits out lists (class "character") and I want to make a new list that has names that are common to two of these character lists.

Example formatting of these lists can be recreated by doing this:

```
fruit <- c("apple", "banana", "plum", "cherry", "strawberry", "mango", "peach")

redstuff <- c("hydrant", "blood", "car", "cherry", "ruby", "toothbrush", "apple")
```

Now I've read that `merge()` can do this type of thing if `all.x=FALSE`. However, I don't think the lists as they stand are in the proper type of formatting.

What's the best way to do this? Do I need to convert both lists to data frames or something first? Also, I'll need the final new list to be a character list again in order to use it as an input, so how do I change it back? Or is there a clean way to do what I need to do without converting the lists to a different format?

Answer (score 4):

`intersect` is the function you are looking for.

```
> intersect(fruit, redstuff)
[1] "apple"  "cherry"
```

see `?intersect` for further details.